# Track logins sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a job that runs on my server to track the last login on my sql server so I can audit inactive users. 
First I enabled track successful logins on the server

I created a table called TRACK_LOGIN and run this daily:

```
 INSERT INTO dbadb.dbo.TRACK_LOGIN (logontime, logon, loginname) EXEC XP_READERRORLOG 0, 1, [LOGIN SUCCEEDED FOR USER]
```

Now that that information is in the TRACK_LOGIN table I query DISTINCT out of that table and put it in another table with this query:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING(LOGINNAME,PATINDEX('%''%',LOGINNAME)+1,PATINDEX('%.%',LOGINNAME)-PATINDEX('%''%',LOGINNAME))FROM TRACK_LOGIN
```

I would also like to query the column logontime along with the distinct login so I have a list daily of who logs in and what time they login?

Please help modify the select statement above to include distinct logins along with their last logontime.

This is intended on allowing me to look back at my users last login and eliminate those on the server that are not used.

Comment: It seems you don't know what you can do when someone answers your question :) You can accept an answer by click on check mark near the answer. Also when you accept an answer, it would be great if you also vote for the answer by click on up arrow near the post. It's not compulsory at all, but it's common, reasonable and recommended. For more information about how does accepting answers work see this [post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow).

Answer (score 2):

I understand that you have already put some real effort into make this work, but I would still suggest to go with a different approach that yields a much cleaner result:

[Logon triggers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb326598.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

This will allow you to insert the right type of data into your table and will not force you to parse back log entries.

This example [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/50620/how-to-create-login-and-logout-trigger-for-client-audit) shows a different use case, but I think you will have no issue to port it to your own problem.

```
CREATE TRIGGER MyLogonTrigger ON ALL SERVER FOR LOGON
AS 
BEGIN
    IF SUSER_SNAME() <> 'sa'
    INSERT INTO Test.dbo.LogonAudit (UserName, LogonDate, spid) 
            VALUES (SUSER_SNAME(), GETDATE(), @@SPID);
END;
GO
ENABLE TRIGGER MyLogonTrigger ON ALL SERVER;
```

Comment: Thanks, but this still leaves the question how to I Select the Distinct username with this example with the most recent LogonDate?

Comment: The answer seems to be an easy `select max(logintime) from tracktable group by login;` but I assume you have a more complicated problem than that. Could you edit your question to show some sample data and an expected output?

Comment: Ok when I create the trigger provided above:  
    
    CREATE TRIGGER MyLogonTrigger ON ALL SERVER FOR LOGON
    AS 
    BEGIN
    IF SUSER_SNAME() <> 'sa'
    INSERT INTO Test.dbo.LogonAudit (UserName, LogonDate, spid) 
            VALUES (SUSER_SNAME(), GETDATE(), @@SPID); 
    END;  
  GO
ENABLE TRIGGER MyLogonTrigger ON ALL SERVER;

it blocks all users except sa

Comment: You do not actually have a table called `Test.dbo.LogonAudit`, do you?

Answer (score 0):

Ok to track logins I did this, I abounded the first method and implemented this: 
First I created a table called logonaudit:

```
 CREATE TABLE LogonAudit
(
    AuditID INT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT PK_LogonAudit_AuditID 
                PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED IDENTITY(1,1)
    , UserName NVARCHAR(255)
    , LogonDate DATETIME
    , spid INT NOT NULL
);
```

I then had to grant insert on that table:

```
GRANT INSERT ON dbadb.dbo.LogonAudit TO public;
```

I created another table called auditloginresults:

```
create table auditLoginResults
(
AuditID INT,
Username NVARCHAR(255),
LogonDate DATETIME,
SPID INT 
);
```

I then created a trigger to log all logins and times to the first table LogonAudit. I had to create a logon called login_audit and allow it to insert into my tables. I then had to use the origional_login() to log the users login, if you dont do this it will block all logins that are not sa

```
CREATE TRIGGER MyLogonTrigger 
ON ALL SERVER WITH EXECUTE AS 'login_audit'
FOR LOGON
AS 
BEGIN
INSERT INTO DBADb.dbo.LogonAudit (UserName, LogonDate, spid) 
        VALUES (ORIGINAL_LOGIN(), GETDATE(), @@SPID);

END;
```

Now I created a job (you will need to create a job to run at a specific time with this code, This is not the code for the job just the code you would run in your job) to query the first table LogonAudit and put the results into the auditloginResults table, after that step I cleaned out the first table LogonAudit by running another step to delete data in the first table. Im not going to post the job to keep the threat clean but here is what is run in the job

The create job step 1--------------------------------------------------------

```
INSERT INTO DBADb.dbo.auditLoginResults
SELECT I.* 
FROM DBADb.[dbo].[LogonAudit]  AS I
INNER JOIN 
       (SELECT UserName, MAX([logondate]) AS MaxDate
        FROM DBADb.[dbo].[LogonAudit] 
        GROUP BY UserName
       ) AS M ON I.logondate = M.MaxDate 
             AND I.UserName = M.UserName
```

`
-----NOW create job to purge the logonaudit table step 2

```
DELETE FROM dbadb.dbo.auditLoginResults;
```

-----now create a stored procedure to execute this will query the auditloginreaults and provide you the last login of everyone that has ever logged into the database

```
SELECT I.* 
FROM DBADb.[dbo].[auditLoginResults]  AS I
INNER JOIN 
           (SELECT UserName, MAX([logondate]) AS MaxDate
            FROM DBADb.[dbo].[ auditLoginResults] 
            GROUP BY UserName
           ) AS M ON I.logondate = M.MaxDate 
                 AND I.UserName = M.UserName
```